# JSON_PARSER_ERROR on PATCH when updating a custom object

Tags: rest-api, api, rest

I am attempting to update a custom object using the Salesforce REST API as described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_update_fields.htm), but I consistently receive this 400 response

```
[
    {
        "message": "The HTTP entity body is required, but this request has no entity body.",
        "errorCode": "JSON_PARSER_ERROR"
    }
]
```

I have tried appending `?_HttpMethod=PATCH` to the url and switching to a `POST`call, but while that yields `200 OK`, it doesn't actually update the object. The object is "updateable" and I do have permission to edit it. Editing it directly in Salesforce works without issues.

Here is my (cleaned) request, as exported from [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) [Version 5.14.9 (5.14.9.1895)].

```
curl --request PATCH \
  --url https://myInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/CUSTOMOBJECT/CUSTOMOBJECTID \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer token' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{
    "Additional_Information__c": "Test additional information"
}'
```

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_usage_rest_resources.htm) for sending HTTP requests with cURL, either a JSON data file needs to be sent or a ".json" extension needs to be appended to the URI.

```
curl --request PATCH \
  --url https://myInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/CUSTOMOBJECT/CUSTOMOBJECTID.json \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer token' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{
    "Additional_Information__c": "Test additional information"
}'
```